# How to display my couchabase JSON to zk TreeModel?

Tags: java, json, tree, zk

Previously i wrote a query which is queries the proper couchbase file.I have a entity for it:

```
class SubMenu{
  String name,url;
  List<SubMenu>; //and of course getters-setters...
}
```

when i queried i get a arrayList of SubMenu:

```
Submenu = [name="menu",url="menu",SubMenu[name = "Submenu1",url="submenu1"]
```

So a SubMenu can contains more Submenu

My JSON:

```
{
"name":"menu",
"url:"menu",
"subMenu":[{
    "name":"submenu",
    "url":"submenu",
    "wubMenu[]
},
    "name":"submenu2",
    "url":"submenu2",
    "wubMenu[]
]
}
```

And i want to build a tree like menu which has two children submenu and submenu2...and so on...and if submenu has other submenus go show it.
I started from [this](https://github.com/simbo1905/zktreemvvm/blob/master/src/main/java/org/github/simbo1905/zktreemvvm/VfsTreeModel.java) example....but i dont know how to solve the override methods...getChild,childCount,isLeaf in my case: ArrayList
Could anyone helps to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty straight forward.

IsLeaf actually means is this bean has children or not.
In your example => return true if `List<SubMenu>` is null or is the size is 0.

childcount => return the size of `List<SubMenu>`

getChild => return the item at index x of the `List`. remember also to throw an error or null when index is higher then size of the `List`.